# Assume $u\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, does $u^q\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ for $q>0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded smooth domain. Let $u\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ be a non-negative $k-$times weakly differentiable function where $p\geq 1$ is arbitrary. Now let $q>0$ be a positive  number. My question is that does $u^q\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ too?

In fact, I'm dealing with the following problem:

Let $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ be a non-negative solution of the following equation:

$$
-\Delta u=\lambda u^{q},
$$
where $\lambda,q>0$. I want to prove that $u\in C^\infty$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Since we are in dimension $2$ and $\Omega$ is smooth, it's natural to know that $u\in C^1$ by the $W^{2,p}$ estimate and Sobolev embedding. Then I'm stuck since I don't know how to prove the infinity smoothness. So if the above proposition is right, things will become more trivial. But if it fails, how can I get the smoothness of $u$?

Any hints and help will be appreciated a lot!

Comment: In general, a function $u \in W^{k,p}$ can be unbounded (when $k \cdot p$ is smaller or equal than the dimension), and for large $q > 0$ it's possible that $|u|^q$ is not even integrable (let alone in $W^{k,p}$). Hence, more assumptions are needed.